# Career advice - SharePoint development

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I am a newly graduated computing science student and have taken up role as a sharepoint developer, working with C# and TypeScript.

I enjoy the work but anyone i have spoken to / read online about sharepoint development have said it awful to work with and isn't generally well regarded. I found that working with sharepoint has a few awkward quirks, but what technology doesn't?

I have also heard back from one or two companies that i applied to before i graduated.

My questions are, how well respected is sharepoint development among experienced  developers? Is it a viable career path? Should i pursue a new job with the other companies i have heard from while i am still fresh from university?

Comment: How would you define viable? Every technology has risks that it may or may not be used in the future, no?

Comment: I get this was shut down and agree.  A better question is what software technologies make the best careers?  In regards to just finding work software with lot of business demand but is maybe difficult to work with is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this is the first question I've posted to stack exchange, please forgive my newbiness

Comment: There are still people ancient maintaining COBOL systems...and having become a critically endangered skill, gray-haired programmers with the ability remain in demand.  That said, considering the hundreds of companies whose business is centered on building new SP applications, you could do well worse.

Answer (score 3):

I have done some Sharepoint development but I mainly specialize in PHP/CMS/LMS solutions and yes a little Wordpress.

First whether or not Sharepoint is a good solution, has a good API, is fun to code, or whatever else is irrelevant.  The fact is that there are hundreds/thousands of companies using Sharepoint and many of these would love to have a good Sharepoint developer.

I worked with someone who turned a basic Sharepoint site into a fully functioning (with tons of bells and whistles) employee tracking and PM tool.  This saved the company well over $1M in 3 years and worked better than most solutions I have seen.

The fact is that most developers are negative about the Sharepoint API (which is lacking and quirky) only strengthens your employment opportunities.  There is nothing wrong with coding niche systems at all.

I have found that if a company goes this route and has a great developer they never stop using that crappy platform.  But if they have poor developers they will move to something else quickly.

So if you are good you will have long-term employment if you want to keep doing that - maybe really long-term.  I don't know how many developers my company has doing legacy stuff.  These guys who wrote code in the late 90s and still supporting it.  Yes eventually their stuff will be replaced.  But guess what?  They will be needed during the switch and quite possibly will know new code better than anyone.

My advise is that there is nothing at all wrong with being a Sharepoint developer.  However please allot a good amount of time staying current with the industry/methodology that you want to be a part of in the future.  Often doing this will allow you to take newer methodologies and implement them into sometimes older/not-quite-as-good APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Well regarded software and viable career are not the same.

SharePoint development is quirky.  But it is popular at the  business level so there is a demand for developers.  The business will often get into a SharePoint site and get so far and discover they need to bring in a developer.  SharePoint is marketed very successfully  but many customer underestimate the amount of development required so it creates demand for developers.